# How can I change TTL values for Cloudfront object caching for my default cache behaviour pattern?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a legacy site and a new site, and I'm using Cloudfront to route traffic to the two different server groups based on URL path (eg. `/new` goes to the new servers, everything else to the old ones).

In AWS Cloudfront, my `Default (*)` path pattern captures all traffic not caught by the other rules, and routes these requests to the legacy site. This site explicitly prevents caching with its headers and I want to override this.

It looks from the AWS Console, though, like I can't do this:

[image: Object caching settings disabled]

All the other cache behaviours (eg. for the `/new` path pattern) allow me to set these options. Does this mean that Cloudfront doesn't allow customisation of TTLs for the default path? If not, the only way I can fix these cache headers will be to manually change them at the source origin, which I'd prefer to avoid.

Is there a way I can change these settings for my default route?

Comment: If you are forwarding all headers to the origin, all caching is disabled, so the setting is not applicable.  Is that what you are doing in the default behavior?

Comment: Also "the origin explicitly prevents caching" needs to be defined precisely because, most likely, [CloudFront will only use Minimum TTL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationDownloadDist) in any event, and browsers will still not cache the object, which may or may not be what you expect.

Comment: Ahh of course, you're right. I'm a fool! I was forwarding all headers, so couldn't choose a setting. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it there.

Comment: And yes – what I meant with the caching statement was that the origin servers set `cache-control: no-cache, no store` and `expires: -1`. I was hoping that adding some minimum TTLs would result in cache hits from Cloudfront (doing this on a test endpoint sees this happen).